# How do I comment on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, comments

I am new to ***stackoverflow.com***. How do I comment on an answer?

I mean, I put one question on *stackoverflow.com*, and I got a good and exact answer. Then I want to comment that it is correct / incorrect. How?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  These type of questions are more appropriate on it's sister site meta.stackoverflow.com, where you can find and create answers related to the functionality of this site and other stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 11):

Please do not leave a comment. Instead, click the up-arrow icon next to answers that helped you, and the down-arrow icon next to answers that were wrong. Please also click the checkmark icon next to the answer that helped you the most or solved your problem completely.

EDIT:
I'm waiting for a conference call to start, so I created a five-second guide for this:

[image: screenshot of upvote/downvote/accept area with labels]

Comment: This is of course, **The One Right Answer** (TM). Maybe @jaleel can use it for practice.

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: This makes assumptions that the OP is only adding a "thanks" comment, not any more detail.

Comment: @rchern, you're right, but I thought that was heavily implied by the OP's wording.

Answer (score 3):

Use the *add comment* link underneath the answer.  Per the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)

> you can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you've asked, even with 1 rep.

To comment on another user's post that isn't an answer to a question of yours, you'll need 50 rep.

Please read [this FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work/19757#19757) on comments so that you know how they work.

Answer (score 1):

Commenting everywhere requires 50 reputation points. You can comment on your own posts from rep 1.

Just click on the `add comment` link below your question, or your answer.

Comment: You can comment on your own question and answers to your own question with 1 rep.